# Compilation issue due to method calls issue in gradle file

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

I am a newbie in kotlin
I am following [Android Room with a View - Kotlin](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view-kotlin#3) and have the following error appearing on the `build.gradle` file.

```
Build file 'C:\Users\suraj.manjunath\AndroidStudioProjects\RoomWordSample\build.gradle' line: 3

Could not compile build file 'C:\Users\suraj.manjunath\AndroidStudioProjects\RoomWordSample\build.gradle'.
> startup failed:
  build file 'C:\Users\suraj.manjunath\AndroidStudioProjects\RoomWordSample\build.gradle': 3: only id(String), alias(Provider), or alias(ProviderConvertible) method calls allowed in plugins {} script block
```

This is my build.gradle(Project Level)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.31'
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.3.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.3.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.20' apply false

}
ext {
    activityVersion = '1.4.0'
    appCompatVersion = '1.4.0'
    constraintLayoutVersion = '2.1.2'
    coreTestingVersion = '2.1.0'
    coroutines = '1.5.2'
    lifecycleVersion = '2.4.0'
    materialVersion = '1.4.0'
    roomVersion = '2.3.0'
    // testing
    junitVersion = '4.13.2'
    espressoVersion = '3.4.0'
    androidxJunitVersion = '1.1.3'
}
```

This is my build.gradle app level

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'

}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.roomwordsample'
    compileSdk 32



    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.roomwordsample"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/atomicfu.kotlin_module'
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$rootProject.appCompatVersion"
    implementation "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:$rootProject.activityVersion"

    // Dependencies for working with Architecture components
    // You'll probably have to update the version numbers in build.gradle (Project)

    // Room components
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$rootProject.roomVersion"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$rootProject.roomVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:$rootProject.roomVersion"

    // Lifecycle components
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$rootProject.lifecycleVersion"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$rootProject.lifecycleVersion"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:$rootProject.lifecycleVersion"

    // Kotlin components
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    api "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$rootProject.coroutines"
    api "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$rootProject.coroutines"

    // UI
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:$rootProject.constraintLayoutVersion"
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:$rootProject.materialVersion"

    // Testing
    testImplementation "junit:junit:$rootProject.junitVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:$rootProject.coreTestingVersion"
    androidTestImplementation ("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:$rootProject.espressoVersion", {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit:$rootProject.androidxJunitVersion"
}
```

I changed the line `ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.31'` to `id "ext.kotlin_version "version '1.5.31'`
This results in the error

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'ext.kotlin_version', version: '1.5.31'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'ext.kotlin_version:ext.kotlin_version.gradle.plugin:1.5.31')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository
    Google
    MavenRepo
    at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.resolveToFoundResult(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:243)
```

Please help in resolving the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Where are you getting this setup from? The module-level `build.gradle` should have this plugins block:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}
```

And the project-level one should have this **buildscript** (not *plugins*) block:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.31'

    ...
}
```

You're getting the error because you're trying to define that `ext.kotlin_version` variable inside a *plugins* block, and it's not allowed there. If you follow the tutorial in your link, this is how it tells you to set things up. You can also look at the solution repo's full [project-level](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-room-with-a-view/blob/kotlin/build.gradle) and [module-level](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-room-with-a-view/blob/kotlin/app/build.gradle) build files, if you want to see the full setup (just bear in mind they're using a newer Gradle version!)

Answer (score 0):

As cactustictacs said, the place where to put the kotlin version is in the build.gradle project level file, it has to be put before the plugins {} block :

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.31' 
......
}
plugins{
.....
}
```